# How to upgrade AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an Application load balancer in production with  `"CreatedTime": "2020-08-25T13:49:18.510000+00:00",`

Trying to setup traffic mirror but get error that I can't as LB created on no nitro instance.

I have an LB on my dev environment created at a later time(2022) and this works.

Can't see anywhere that shows this information. Have tried `describe-load-balancers`

My question is I would have expected aws to have LB updated in background periodically which doesn't seem the case. So how does one update with no downtime?